# Face detection using opencv on hadoop from video

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop

we are working on video analysis on HDFS .we want to detect faces from video.
but I don't have idea about how to extract images from video on hadoop and how to save images on hdfs.
      Please help us for extracting video and store this images on hadoop file system.
       Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested opencv with hadoop..!